# Pig: UDF not returning expected resultset

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

This is the sample data on which i was working:

```
Peter   Wilkerson   27  M
James   Owen    26  M
Matt    Wo  30  M
Kenny   Chen    28  M
```

I created a simple `UDF` for filtering the age like this:

```
public class IsApplicable extends FilterFunc {

    @Override
    public Boolean exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        if(tuple == null || tuple.size() > 0){
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Object object = tuple.get(0);
            if(object == null){
                return false;
            }
            int age = (Integer)object;
            return age > 28;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Script I used for using this UDF:

```
records = LOAD '~/Documents/data.txt' AS (firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray);
filtered_records = FILTER records BY com.udf.IsApplicable(age);
dump filtered_records;
```

Dumping does not display any record. Please let me know where I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple.size() > 0` condition is `always true` in the `if stmt`, so it will never go to the `try block(ie filtering logic)`, that is the reason you are getting empty result. Can you change the if condition like this?

```
     System.out.println("TupleSize="+tuple.size());
     if(tuple == null || tuple.size() < 0){
            return false;
        }
```

**Sample debug output in console:**

```
2015-02-13 07:40:46,994 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: records[3,10],records[-1,-1],filtered_records[4,19] C:  R: 
TupleSize=1
TupleSize=1
TupleSize=1
```

Comment: Is there some way to debug the java code for Pig UDF?

Comment: For debugging, i will always use System.out.println() command. It is very easy to use and also the output will be printed in the console. For  example if you want check the value of tuple.size() in the UDF code, just add the stmt  above the if condition, System.out.println("TupleSize="+tuple.size()); , when you run the pig script the output will displayed in the console.  Note: If you do any change in the UDF code, make sure to compile and generate the jar file, otherwise changes will not be reflected. Updated the answer with system command.

Answer (score 0):

This is returning `false` for all of the rows:

```
if (tuple == null || tuple.size() > 0) {
    return false;
}
```

This is fetching the `userName` and not `age`:

```
Object object = tuple.get(0);
```